# Spark RDD.aggregate vs RDD.reduceByKey?

Tags: apache-spark

I have and RDD[String] containing one word per line. The size is currently very small, 10-20k lines, but the goal is to scale this up to hundreds of millions of lines. The issue I have is that doing a map/reduceByKey operation is taking surprisingly long even for this small dataset. I run the following:

```
val wordcount = filtered.map(w => (w,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

and for 16780 lines it takes 12321 ms on a 2 GHz i7 8 GB RAM machine. I found that there is a method called aggregate that might be more memory efficient and hence faster:

```
aggregate[U: ClassTag](zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, T) => U, combOp: (U, U) => U): U
```

I can't quite figure out how to implement this in my case. I'm assuming it should be something like

```
aggregate(collection.immutable.Map)(??)
```

So my questions are

**1) Does it make sense to use aggregate instead of reduceByKey**

**2) If it does, how would it be implemented?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose, the fastest would be `countByValue`:

> Return the count of each unique value in this RDD as a map of (value, count) pairs. The final combine step happens locally on the master, equivalent to running a single reduce task.

Usage is trivial:

```
val wordcount = filtered.countByValue
```

The implementation of this method should answer the second question :)

By the way, `reduceByKey` shouldn't be taking that long. It looks like pre-computation (i.e., filtering) is taking most of these 12 seconds. To verify it, `persist` RDD before counting:

```
val persisted = filtered.persist
val wordcount = persisted.countByValue
```

Comment: `persist/cache` only help if you are going to use the cached RDD more than once, otherwise they actually slow your program down

Comment: Thank you! There was indeed something wrong earlier in the process, but I fixed that and switched to countByValue and it seems to run fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`countByValue` would be the fastest way to do this, however its implementation uses hash maps and merges them so if you have a large amount of data this approach may not scale well (especially when you consider how many issues spark already has with memory). You may want to use the standard way of counting in map reduce which would be to map the line and 1 as pairs then `reduceBykey` like this:

```
val wordCount = filtered.map((_,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect()
```

You could also consider using `countByValueApprox` generally when dealing with data this large an approximation will generally be good enough and by far the most efficient approach (though it still uses hash maps so with many unique words you could still fail). You might consider using this if you can't get `countByValue` to run.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'm trying to get to know Spark, what issues with memory are you referring to @aaronman? Something I should watch out for?

Comment: @langkilde not necessarily anything specific just that in production many people seem to have trouble getting totally correct spark jobs to run without crashing on large amounts of data. I expect many of these issues to be resolved in later versions since spark is still young